# Simple way to resolve 2D elastic collision between circles

Tags: java, 2d, android-canvas, collision, resolve

I need the simplest solution for resolving 2D elastic collision between circles, each circle has equal mass with the others.

The environment is Android canvas in which the Y axis is growing towards down. Logic representation of the circle is class *PlayerBall* which has successful collision detection. PlayerBall has fields:

**x** and **y** position of center of the circle

**velX** and **velY** velocity vector of the circle movement represented as two scalar values which can be positive or negative.

**diameter** - diameter of the circle

```
public static void resolveCollision(PlayerBall ballOne, PlayerBall ballTwo) 
{
    double collisionAngle = Math.atan2(ballTwo.y - ballOne.y, ballTwo.x - ballOne.x); // angle for ball one
    // calculating new velocities between ballOne and ballTwo
    ...
    // setting the new velocities for both balls
    ballOne.setVelocity((float)ballOneVelX, (float)ballOneVelY);
    ballTwo.setVelocity((float)ballTwoVelX, (float)ballwTwoVelY);

}
```

I am expecting that velocities of the balls change according to formula defined in this article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_collision#Two-dimensional_collision_with_two_moving_objects

Answer (score 1):

If you know the x and y velocity of both masses then you don't actually need the angle of collision. The resultant x and y forces on the balls can be calculated as a product of their respective masses, and velocities.

You can define this relationship by the formula:

[image: V_xr1 = (V_x1 * (m1 - m2) + (2 * m2 * V_x2)) / (m1 + m1)]

Where V_x1 represents the velocity purely in the x plane, m1 and m2 are the masses of the balls. This will give you the resultant x velocity. You can apply the same logic to calculate the resultant forces in the y direction.

```
let newVelX1 = (vel1.vX * (m1 - m2) + (2 * m2 * vel2.vX)) / (m1 + m2);
let newVelY1 = (vel1.vY * (m1 - m2) + (2 * m2 * vel2.vY)) / (m1 + m2);
```

Comment: Masses are equals so the formula will be newVelX1 = velX2; newVelY1= velY2; and it will not behave like [this](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2c/Elastischer_sto%C3%9F_2D.gif)

Comment: Nope if the masses are equal only the first term resolves to 0. Think you need to check your math

Comment: that equation sort of falls flat with say, object A at (0,2) going at speed (5,0) colliding with another object B at (2,0) going at (-5,0). You get a bounce-back but no conversion of horizontal to vertical speed, which is sort of bad